# I'm trying to compile bitcoind on Windows but build_unix for db-4.8.30.NC is empty. What do I need to do?

Tags: windows, compiling

I've been working on setting up the proper environment to compile litecoin, and have been following the instructions from this:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=1dl8pkva2oqpjsd3h455k7hrj7&topic=149479.0;all

> 2.2 Berkeley DB: http://download.oracle.com/berkeley-db/db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz
>
> We'll use version 4.8 to preserve binary wallet compatibility.
>
> From a MinGW shell unpack the source archive, configure, edit line 113 of db.h then make:
>
> Code:

```
cd /c/deps/

tar xvfz db-4.8.30.NC.tar.gz

cd db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix

../dist/configure --disable-replication --enable-mingw --enable-cxx
```

> after configuring make sure to edit your build_unix/db.h by replacing line 113:
>
> Code:

```
typedef pthread_t db_threadid_t;
```

> with
>
> Code:

```
typedef u_int32_t db_threadid_t;
```

I was all set to do it, but this happened:
[image: The build_unix folder is empty]

I've tried getting db-4.8.30.NC from multiple sources, but no luck—the build_unix folder is always empty.

So what's the deal?

Comment: I just downloaded Berkeley DB from the link and had no problems.  The db-4.8.30NC.tar.gz is 21.7MB.  Is this the size of your file?

Comment: I have no problem downloading the file; can you tell me what's inside your build_unix directory? I only have an .IGNORE_ME file.

Comment: There are 793 files, one of which is .IGNORE_ME.  There is also a .libs subdirectory.  Sounds like your tarball wasn't unpacked correctly or it was truncated.

Comment: Can I have your link? I tried both mingw and 7zip to open it. I tried the windows zip viewer for a zip version.

Comment: I mislead you because I have already built Berkely DB.  I went back and looked at the .tar.gz file again and it does contain just the .IGNORE_ME file.  You just need to run the configure and make commands to create all of the files in the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build_unix directory contains just the .IGNORE_ME file in the distribution.  The directory is populated by the make command.

```
../dist/configure --disable-replication --enable-mingw --enable-cxx
make
```

You do not need to edit db.h in the latest distribution since they have already corrected the typedef.

Comment: ../dist/configure --enable-cxx
make
this will also do

Comment: im trying to build this on windows, i dont see a configure file. can someone point out

Comment: I can't believe I missed this answer. I'll see if I still have that stuff on my laptop, maybe I can get it going when I have time!